# Google App Engine - Getting Server URL

Tags: android, google-app-engine, url

I deployed my highscoreserver-code to Google App Engine. Now I need a URL to send a request to the server. But I can't find a URL in my dashboard...
What I need is this:

```
http://myhighscoreserver.appspot.com/THIS-PART-I-NEED?name="test"&points="0"
```

What should I insert in the URL above?

EDIT: THIS-PART-I-NEED = class-name of the servlet

Comment: Java, Go or Python? If Java, http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/1.3/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html#getRequestURL%28%29

Comment: How do you know you need anything at all?

Comment: I use Java (Android). But I think you have got me wrong. I read a few Google App Engine tutorials and I always saw a URL like:  
  http://myhighscoreserver.appspot.com /******?name="test"&points="0"  

Now I need to find out what I must paste into these *****.

Comment: "THIS-PART-I-NEED" where you need this from? inside servlet or Android ?

Comment: I need this in my Android Application to build a HttpGet.

Comment: Ok, I found the solution. I must paste the class-name in the link >.<

Comment: or you can see the mapping in web.xml file http://myhighscoreserver.appspot.com/highscoreserver

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://myhighscoreserver.appspot.com/THIS-PART-I-NEED?name="test"&points="0"  it's pretty easy: THIS-PART-I-NEED = class-name of the servlet